# SQL Injection and php performance checking - revised

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

This piece of code selects from the left table and will list the content in the right hand table. This is a working code but I would like to see how a professional would protect and make it faster.

Any suggestion (with some code) would be appreciated. Thanks a lot

PS: There is also a little glitch with it: after deleting it lose the selected item on the right list.

```
<?php include("db_con1.php");?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="test.php">

<div id="left">
<?php
  $queryl = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM test1 ORDER BY name ASC');
  $queryl->execute();
?>

<ul>

  <?php foreach ($queryl as $i => $rowl) { ?>

  <li>
   <?php if ($i)?>
  <input name="checkbox_del[]" id="test_<?php echo $i ?>" type="checkbox" value="<? echo $rowl['id']; ?>"/>
  <label for="test_<?php echo $i ?>">
   <a href="test1.php?gid=<?php echo $rowl['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rowl['name']; ?></a>
  </label>
 </li>
  <?php } ?>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="right">

<?php
  if(isset($_GET['gid'])) {
   $gid=$_GET['gid'];    
   $queryr = $pdo->prepare('SELECT test3.name FROM test1, test2, test3 WHERE test1.id=test2.groupid AND test3.id=test2.peopleid AND test1.id='.$gid.' ORDER BY test3.name ASC');
   $queryr->execute();
  }
?>

<ul>

  <?php foreach ($queryr as $i => $rowr) { ?>

    <li>
      <?php if ($i)?>
      <input name="checkbox_del[]" id="test_<?php echo $i ?>" type="checkbox" value="<? echo $rowr['id']; ?>"/>
      <label for="test_<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $rowr['name']; ?></label>
    </li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="del" value="Delete the selected items">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['del'])) {
echo "Don't delete:)";
  for ($c = 0; $c < count($_POST['checkbox1_del']); $c++){
    $checkbox1_del = $_POST['checkbox1_del'][$c];
    $sql = 'UPDATE test1 SET status=0, log="'.date("Y-m-d").'"WHERE id='.$checkbox1_del;
    echo $sql;
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
  }

  for ($c = 0; $c < count($_POST['checkbox2_del']); $c++){
    $checkbox2_del = $_POST['checkbox2_del'][$c];
    $sql = 'UPDATE test2 SET status=0, log="'.date("Y-m-d").'"WHERE id='.$checkbox2_del;
    echo $sql;
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
   }

    if($query){
      echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=test1.php\">";
     }
 }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Revision 1: now I have had some feedback so I just would like to ask which is better, would this be better?

```
<?php
if(is_numeric($_GET['gid'])) {
 $queryr = $pdo->prepare('SELECT test3.name FROM test1, test2, test3 WHERE test1.id=test2.groupid AND test3.id=test2.peopleid AND test1.id=:id ORDER BY test3.name ASC');
 if( $queryr->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id'])) ) {
    $result = $queryr->fetch();
 }
}
?>
```

or this?

```
<?php
if(is_numeric($_GET['gid'])) {
 $gid = $_GET['gid'];    
 $queryr = $pdo->prepare('SELECT test3.name FROM test1, test2, test3 WHERE test1.id = test2.groupid AND test3.id = test2.peopleid AND test1.id = :gid ORDER BY test3.name ASC');
 $queryr->bindParam(':gid', $gid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $queryr->execute();
?>
```

instead of this? (please be polite if I did something wrong as I am a beginner:)

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['gid'])) {
   $gid=$_GET['gid'];    
   $queryr = $pdo->prepare('SELECT test3.name FROM test1, test2, test3 WHERE test1.id=test2.groupid AND test3.id=test2.peopleid AND test1.id='.$gid.' ORDER BY test3.name ASC');
   $queryr->execute();
  }
?>
```

Comment: If you're really willing to learn, go out on the web and read some tutorials. Search for "prepared statements" and "input sanitation"

Comment: thanks for the comment I've been there and the plenty different opinion about the whole thing. I would try to ask here as well. More opinions can narrows down the answer.

Comment: You might want to consider to look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of stackoverflow. They're dedicated to reviewing existing code and improving it.

Comment: Doesn't it run fast enough already?

Comment: I don't know yet as I have to complete this function and I will upload with a larger amount of data to check it.

Answer (score 3):

Just remember, if there are any variable **which does not do escape** in your sql,  there could be SQL injection hole.

Don't use the variable in your sql, use the **placeholder** for prepared statement.

Comment: thanks for your hint. can $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string); wokr with pdo?

Comment: @Andras With pdo, you should use `PDO::quote()`, but you are strongly recommended to use `PDO::prepare()` to prepare SQL statements with bound parameters instead of using `PDO::quote()` to interpolate user input into an SQL statement.

Comment: thanks for the comment could you have a look at my 'homeworked' solution?:)

Comment: @Andras If your id is int, the second way. By the way, you can also use  `bindValue()` to avoid define the `$gid`.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT test3.name FROM test1, test2, test3 WHERE test1.id=test2.groupid AND test3.id=test2.peopleid AND test1.id=...` is open to SQL injections... http://xkcd.com/327/

the same with `UPDATE test1 SET status=0, log="'.date("Y-m-d").'"WHERE id='.$checkbox1_del;`..

your page is open to simple SQL attacks.. you should learn about SQL injection and prepared statements.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. Would you be so kind to show some best practice how to fix them?

Comment: i said "you should learn about SQL injection and prepared statements." try googling for that.

Comment: well done, regarding your revision, in the first case you simply execute a statement, noting is returned... so second case is really the only useable one

Comment: thanks Quarmis, I am glad that I have learned something again today:)

Comment: @Quarmis, I found this: Although bindValue() escapes quotes it does not escape "%" and "_", so be careful when using LIKE. A malicious parameter full of %%% can dump your entire database if you don't escape the parameter yourself. PDO does not provide any other escape method to handle it.

Comment: I dont know why that works like this. But you now need to learn about input sanitizing. look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php